# Change Proxy of an Application

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to write a program that changes proxy settings of other applications. Is it possible to change proxy settings of an application that uses internet via Java? Am I only allowed to change browsers' settings using system registry?

Answer (score 0):

Use the -DPROXY_HOST=somehost and -DPROXY_PORT=portno JVM parameters.

Comment: I'm not trying to set JVM's proxy, I'm trying to write a program that changes proxy settings of other applications.